# Как проектировать класс исключений?

Tags: c++, исключения

Что правильней - располагать класс пользовательского исключения в одном хедере с классом, который в основном генерерует исключения этого типа (как, например, `boost::any` и `boost::bad_any_cast` - в одном хедере) или же всю иерархию пользовательских классов исключений выносить в отдельное единое место? Кажется, первый вариант предпочтительней, ведь не придется тогда модифицировать какой-то сторонний хедер...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как по мне, то это зависит от *конкретного проекта* - что удобнее для понимания, работы и т.д. Если иерархия исключений привязана к классам, с которыми работает - то разумнее конкретные исключения, привязанные к классам, давать вместе с классами.
Если иерархия исключении описывает разные ситуации, которые могут быть в разных классах - разумнее вынести в отдельный файл иерархию исключений.

*По-моему, так* (с) Пух